# Firebase admin-sdk: 'Permission denied'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am trying to access my firebase db using the admin-sdk through my python server. Following this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-admin-privileges), I configure my app:

```
from firebase_admin import credentials, db
firebase_admin.initialize_app(
    credentials.Certificate('secret/serviceAccountKey.json'),
    {'databaseURL': 'https://my-app.firebaseio.com'})
```

Where `secret/serviceAccountKey.json` is the file downloaded from the project setting's [service accounts](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk) tab

Not, I try to `get()` the database values from the db's ref:

```
    try:
        ref = db.reference('')
        print ref.get()
    except Exception as err:
        print 'ERROR>>>', err
```

But I get the following error in the `except` block:

> ERROR>>> ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))

---

**Additional notes (FYIs):**

1. According to [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/16#issuecomment-289094258), I have ensured that my current service account has the **Editor** role and not a **Viewer** role.
2. My db rules are public for now: `{ "rules": { ".read": "true", ".write": "true" } }`
3. Not sure if this is relevant but just an FYI: I don't have any db user for now, ie. the "Authentication" tab in the console doesn't show any users.

Comment: Is your service account created against the correct Firebase project?

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka Yes

Comment: Actually this seems to be a low level error in your runtime (e.g. https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/3018). How and where is your code deployed?